# Toolbar is deleting my back Button in the NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a Detail view of a list where I navigate to from my main view:

```
NavigationView {
    ...
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
        Text(entity.name ?? "Unknown")
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in my DetailView I can see the back button to my Main view:

```
struct DetailView: View {
  
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ...
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Deatil")
        /*.toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                
                Button(action: {
                    ...
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                }
                
            }
            
        }*/
    }
}
```

Its all fine till I use the toolbar. Then I only see the toolbar but not the navigation to the last view. Why? Usually this should work, right?

Comment: Is toolbar supposed to be commented out in your DetailView?

Comment: Works for me. But you can always try another placement like `ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing)`.

Comment: Confirm as work with Xcode 12 / iOS 14. Do you use some Xcode beta?

Comment: Works file in BigSur, Xcode 12 Beta 2, iOS 14.2

Comment: Yes it’s BigSur, Xcode 12 Beta 2 and iOS 14. does it also work for you if you have another DetailView2? So you navigate in two times.

Comment: Yes. The "Back" text changed to "Deatil" because of the `navigationBarTitle` change in the first Detail. I'll post my code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ToolbarBug: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailViewToolbarBug()) {
                Text("Unknown")
            }
        }
    }
}
struct DetailViewToolbarBug: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailViewToolbarBug()) {
                Text("Unknown")
            }
        Form {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailViewToolbarBug()) {
                Text("Unknown")
            }
            Text("form text")
        }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Deatil")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ToolbarBug_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ToolbarBug()
    }
}
```

Comment: Lorem, your code doesn't reproduce the bug because you haven't placed a state changing/view-refreshing action in your toolbar button. If you do, you'll be able to reproduce the bug. I can confirm that this is still an issue in Xcode 12.2.

Answer (score 19):

I solved it! After experimenting further I discovered that by adding the following toolbar item you can prevent the back button from disappearing in a refreshed view more than three views deep in the navigation hierarchy.

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {Text("")}
```

Note: `EmptyView()` will not work. The bug seems to need an active toolbar item in the leading position to prevent the back button from disappearing when a view is refreshed three or more views deep in a hierarchy.

As I listed before, when not using this new workaround suggested above, there are a few additional caveats to consider in dealing with this bug.

- `navigationBarItems(trailing:)` is deprecated
- using
  `navigationBarItems(trailing:)` and `toolbar(content:)` in the same
  `NavigationView` hierarchy (even when in different views) to avoid
  this bug will cause a number of visual glitches (duplicate back
  buttons etc.)
- Using `toolbar(content:)` that refreshes the view more
  than ***three views deep*** in a navigation hierarchy will remove the
  ability (both the button and swipe gesture) to navigate back in that
  hierarchy.
- for what it's worth, if you specifically indicate the `trailing` location of a toolbar item and keep that item within the first two views of the view hierarchy, and you avoid any use of default/ `primaryAction` or leading placement, and any use of a `navigationBarItem`, you can avoid most of these bugs.

Comment: Ive also experienced this issue being related only to iPhone devices. The issue does not seem to affect the iPad.

Comment: This isn't work for me all the time. I sometimes get the title of the prior screen. So, it looks like "< Title" and not "< Back".

Comment: This fixed the issue for me ! Is there a bug filed for this already?