# SwiftUi Navigation Bar Button disappears after entering the third View (Controller)

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

I have a huge Problem with SwiftUi. The "Backbutton" in a really Simple NavigationView Hierarchy disappears on the third View. If I go one view further, the Backbutton is there again and I can go back.

I searched like 3 Hours but only found this [SwiftUI: Back button disappears when clicked on NavigationLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59589399/swiftui-back-button-disappears-when-clicked-on-navigationlink)

Obviously this doesn't solve my Problem.

Thanks for any Help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toolbar is deleting my back Button in the NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64405106/toolbar-is-deleting-my-back-button-in-the-navigationview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the Problem!

The .toolbar modifier on the NavigationView hides the Backbutton in a Buggy way!

Comment: I feel like this doesn't actually explain much. Did you discover any more info as to what the "buggy way" is, or why it might be behaving that way?

Comment: I don't think it's just that, even the slide-back gesture doesn't work when the bug occurs to me.

Answer (score 10):

For me the issue was a bit different - the back button disappeared on the third view only after interacting with the third view, e.g. clicking into the list view.

My workaround is to use the old .navigationBarItems instead of .toolbar, so:

```
 .navigationBarItems(trailing:
    Menu {
       Button(action: {
          //some action
       }) {
          //some label
       }
       Button(action: {
          //some action
       }) {
          //some label
       }                                        
    }
    label: {
       //some label
    }
 )
```

instead of:

```
.toolbar {
   ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
      Menu {
         Button(action: {
            //some action
         }) {
            //some label
         }
         Button(action: {
            //some action
         }) {
            //some label
         }                        
      }
      label: {
         //some label
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm encountering the same bug too. But while using navigationBarItems does fix the issue, this method is deprecated. The bug also affects any attempt to use the bottom toolbar as well.

Answer (score 9):

I found another workaround for who doesn't want to use a deprecated method.

Just add in your `.toolbar` this `ToolBarItem`:

```swift
.toolbar {

    // ... other toolbar items

    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        Text("")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution which seems to be working on `Xcode 12.4`:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
    HStack {}
}
```

Comment: Just adding this above my ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) worked like a charm everywhere. Also still works in Xcode 13+

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to make your code cleaner

```
/// A ToolbarItem wrapper to work around the back button disappearance bug in SwiftUI 2.
struct NavbarBackButtonDisappearanceWorkaroundItem: ToolbarContent {
    var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            Color.clear
        }
    }
}
```

Use as follows:

```
.toolbar {
   NavbarBackButtonDisappearanceWorkaroundItem()
   SomeOtherUsefulItem()        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution of this problem. If you are not using .toolbar nor .navigationBarItems you should simply add .navigationBarItems(trailing: EmptyView()) to you children. This will always keep your back button alive)

```
   var body: some View {
      ScrollView() {
        ...
      }
       .navigationBarItems(trailing: EmptyView())
     }
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

you need to add to your NavigationView

```
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? This does not appear to fix the issue.